# Matplotlib: IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I m trying to plot the numpy array with scatter function. Below is the code:
at line mtp.scatter, i get the index error.

numpy array is [ 1.   1.   3.   3.   1.1  1.1  1.3  1.3]

Corresponding color is ['red', 'green', 'red', 'red']

Error message: 
mtp.scatter(X_traintest[:,0],X_traintest[:,1],s=170,c=Y_colorset[:])
IndexError: too many indices for array

```
X_traintest=np.array([[]])
X_traintest=np.append(X_traintest, X_trainset)

num1=len(X_trainset)
num2=len(X_testset)
for i in range (num2):
    X_traintest=np.append(X_traintest,X_testset[i], axis=0)
    emptarray=np.zeros(num1)
    for j in range (num1):
        emptarray[j]=mindist(X_testset[i], X_trainset[j])

        print emptarray
    min_index=np.argmin(emptarray)

    Y_colorset.append(Y_colorset[min_index])
    print X_traintest
    print Y_colorset

mtp.figure()        
mtp.scatter(X_traintest[:,0],X_traintest[:,1],s=170,c=Y_colorset[:])
mtp.show()
```

Comment: Could you add the dimensions of `X_trainset` and `X_testset`?

Comment: Dimension of X_trainset : (2,2)
Dimension of X_testset : (2,2)
Dimension of X_traintest : (4, )

Comment: Is it the same for the testset?

Comment: I made a mistake in the question:
    X_traintest=np.array([[]])

    X_traintest=np.append(X_traintest, X_trainset)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `X_traintest` is a one-dimensional array, and you're trying to provide more than one dimensional index. (Namely two: `[:, 0]`)

Answer (score 1):

This error arises when your input sizes are inconsistent.

Check the length of all of your inputs, namely

- X_traintest[:,0]
- X_traintest[:,1]
- Y_colorset[:]

Also, check whether each of the above expressions are the same in dimension (1D)

Comment: Looks like the dimension is causing the issue. Since X_traintest = [1.   1.   3.   3.   1.1  1.1  1.3  1.3]
and Y_colorset = ['red', 'green', 'red', 'red']
I need to set the value of X_trainset to  [[1. ,  1.] ,  [3. ,  3.]  , [1.1 , 1.1] , [1.3 , 1.3]]